# Early modern tag needs clarification as to its purpose

Tags: discussion, tags

[early-modern](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/early-modern) has no wiki summary, and IMHO would definitely need one.

**edit**: or, if nobody know what it is supposed to mean, it could be removed of course.

Comment: I've only found one question tagged as early modern, which to me fit the 20th century tag better.

Comment: @canadiancreed: uh? I see 7 of them...

Comment: You're correct. sorry I searched incorrectly, returning only unanswered instead of all.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any ideas or suggestions as to what it should be, then please submit it. Frankly, I'm not sure what it was intended to represent!

Comment: I'm not sure either, or I would've done it, sorry...

Comment: I'd concur, while it's nice for us Mods to adjust tags as needed the community really needs to build these up.  It's nice you bring it up, and its good to have other eyes on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the questions I found would fit better with having the specific century being the time related tag used for those questions. I'd assume the purpose that this tag was created for was to give an era based tag? If so, probably one(s) that more reflected the eras might be in order, such as "age of sail", or "renaissance", although you could start to get tag overload if we headed full steam in that direction.

Comment: That was brought up early on about tags and I have a feeling we'll hit it again and again, I already did some clean up with the USA tag so this is just another.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bunch of work on tag wikis over the last two or three weeks. I'm working my way through the tags page by frequency of use, which should at least give us the basis for some content that we, as site users, can all improve on.

If only there were more questions on the areas of history I know most about (mainly High Mediæval to Early Modern Europe, plus some aspects of European colonialism) then I could contribute in a more obviously-useful manner  ;o)

Anyway, my suggested text was accepted last week, so we have [some content on the tag wiki](https://history.stackexchange.com/tags/early-modern/info) now, at least.